# ArrayList with if else comapring

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a program which consist two readings,one with less than '100' reading and another with more than '100'reading. Now I have made their ArrayList to store different readings in one.

Now when I use if statement on them I get a following error : **Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.util.ArrayList>', 'double'**

I am new to Java coding and currently learning it. Please help me, by guiding how can I achieve this task or if there is any alternative solution to this.

```
public class DataGen implements SourceFunction<String> {
boolean running = true;
@Override
public void run(SourceContext <String> ctx) throws Exception {
    try{
        while (running) {
            double vibReading1 = 65.563456;
            double vibReading2 = 75.234450;
            double vibReading3 = 85.987653;
            double vibReading4 = 95.854524;
            double vibReading5 = 98.854524;


            double vibDefReading = 100.000000;

            ArrayList<Double> vibReadingless100 = new ArrayList <Double> ();
            vibReadingless100.add (vibReading1);
            vibReadingless100.add (vibReading2);
            vibReadingless100.add (vibReading3);
            vibReadingless100.add (vibReading4);
            vibReadingless100.add (vibReading5);

            double viBReading1 = 110.453456;
            double viBReading2 = 120.126543;
            double viBReading3 = 130.827468;
            double viBReading4 = 140.082354;
            double viBReading5 = 150.432356;

            ArrayList<Double> vibReadingabove100 = new ArrayList <Double> ();
            vibReadingabove100.add (viBReading1);
            vibReadingabove100.add (viBReading2);
            vibReadingabove100.add (viBReading3);
            vibReadingabove100.add (viBReading4);
            vibReadingabove100.add (viBReading5);

            for (int i = 0; i<100;i++) {

                ctx.collect ("Vibration normal Reading: " + vibReadingless100);
                Thread.sleep (100);
            }
            for (int j =0;j<100;j++){

                ctx.collect ("Vibration WARNING Reading: " + vibReadingabove100);
                Thread.sleep (100);
            }

            ArrayList <ArrayList <Double>> RegularReading = new ArrayList <> ();
            RegularReading.add (vibReadingless100);
            RegularReading.add (vibReadingabove100);

            for(Double item : RegularReading) {
                if (item > vibDefReading) {
                    ctx.collect (" -- ALERT Vibration Above threshold!: " + item);
                }
            }
            running = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}

@Override
public void cancel() {
    running = false;
}}
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of typos here (like List and list). It would help to have those fixed to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Do you want to check if the list contains at least one Double value that is > 100? If that's the case you should order it descending and check the first element.

Comment: The > is the least of the problem. You should get elmenent of the list before using > and not the whole list. But that's not the only problem with the code

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Considering that the asker said he gets a compile-time-error in the code that's really no surprise that it doesn't compile and not really that worth pointing out.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS To me it seems that he wants to check if the "threshhold" has been surpassed in which case `rr.size()` would make sense.

Comment: sorry guys, I copy pasted my old code. I have updated it.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDER Hi, thanks. I want it like at first "list" values are executed, when its done then the "List" values gets executed. As you can see I have to set a condition where if the readings goes above 100, I want to print an the ALERT. Which is obviously going to happen from "List". But I don't know if I can do this with ArrayList and if else condition or any other way.

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you wrote `if (rr> vibReading){`  ?

Comment: @Vyncent my 'vibReading' has a 'default' double value given by me. Which later I will use it to compare with 'rr' values between both 'list' and 'List', if reading is bigger than 'vibReaing' then I want it to return the output. This is just an dummy example I am trying this for one of my projects.

Comment: @L.Spillner Hi, I even tried that but it gave me error in comparison of int with double value. By that error I am guessing '.size()' takes int values only.

Comment: Sorry, terrible terrible naming. Use A) names that mean something like `vauesBelow100` and maybe `valuesAbove100` ... instead of list, List, rr ... which all mean  nothing, an worse, confuse readers without any need to. B) never ever use names like List that "overlay" existing names (java.util.List class)

Comment: @GhostCat Yup, I know it's a blunder. So sorry for all these confusion. I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: Thats the thing: blunder accumulates easily. And then, when you somehow get your code to work, there is typically no time left to improve the code, you know, its working, good enough. Thus: don't allow blunder to come into existence. Start worrying about writing good *while* you are writing it, not afterwards. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare a list with a number. That's what the message is saying, too.

If you want to find out whether any of the values in the list are above the given value, use a cycle:

```
for (Double item : rr) {
    if (item > vibDefReading) {
        ctx.collect (" -- ALERT Vibration Above threshold!: " + item);
    }
}
```

with optional `break` if you want to stop at first high reading.

Comment: Hi, If I try that I get an error saying : Incompatible types.
Required:
java.util.ArrayList
<java.lang.Double>
Found:
java.lang.Double and if I change parameter of item to ArrayList it goes in same trouble again.

Comment: You didn't state at which place did it give this error.

Comment: Sorry, it gives me this error at : for (Double item : rr)

Comment: That's because `rr` is of type `ArrayList <ArrayList <Double>>`. Change its declaration to `List<Double> rr = new ArrayList <> ();`. Also use `addAll()` when copying contents from another list.

Comment: @Timir and Jiri thanks this resolved my issue. Thank you!